# How to include a project that is not installed system wide in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to include this C++ https://github.com/sikang/DecompUtil package into my project, but I  am not exactly sure how to do it in my CMakelists.txt . I kept on encountering this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindDecompUtil.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "DecompUtil", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "DecompUtil" with
  any of the following names:

    DecompUtilConfig.cmake
    decomputil-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "DecompUtil" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "DecompUtil_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "DecompUtil" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Steps to replicate the issue:

1. `git clone https://github.com/sikang/DecompUtil` into project directory
2. `cd DecompUtil`
3. `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make` to build the package (success)
4. `cd project_root`
5. `mkdir build && cd build`
6. `cmake ..` (error is here)

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(test)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/DecompUtil)

add_subdirectory(DecompUtil)

find_package(DecompUtil REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${DECOMP_UTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(test src/test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test DecompUtil)

install(TARGETS
test
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

and my project structure looks like this

[image]

Inside test.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <decomp_geometry/polyhedron.h>

int main(){
    Polyhedron<3> poly3DViz;
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to mix `add_subdirectory(DecompUtil)` and `find_package(DecompUtil REQUIRED)`. You only need one of those. I'd suggest you just use `add_subdirectory`. `add_subdirectory` will make that project part of your own project's buildsystem. `find_package` expects the thing to already be built. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @user I have edited the question to include build steps for the DecompUtil package. I also edited my CMakeLists and removed find_package(DecompUtil REQUIRED). Unfortunately i encounter another issue, in which the package library could not be found ..
fatal error: decomp_geometry/polyhedron.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <decomp_geometry/polyhedron.h>

Comment: ^ To elaborate more on above,
`cmake ..` throws no error however,
`cmake --build .` throws  
fatal error: decomp_geometry/polyhedron.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <decomp_geometry/polyhedron.h>

Comment: check the include directories of that cpp file in the compile_commands.json (use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) Let's see what you're include directories are.

Comment: So I did `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)` in my CMakeLists.txt and tried rebuilding but could not find any compile_commands.json in my project folder

Comment: it goes into the build folder, and is only supported for Ninja and Makefile generators.

Comment: weird... looking at https://github.com/sikang/DecompUtil/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt, I don't even see a library target defined called DecompUtil, nor do I see any include directories commands that add that project's `include/` directory to anything. and I can't even tell what it's https://github.com/sikang/DecompUtil/blob/master/decomp_utilConfig.cmake is trying to do... either I'm missing something (totally possible), or this is just a case of a library with bad CMake usage, in which case you have to manually specify the include directories on your own target yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to get it to work by specifying the include directory of the package, `include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/DecompUtil/include` in CMakeLists.txt. It seems that it is a header only library so I guess I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
  Add the installation prefix of "DecompUtil" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "DecompUtil_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
```

[decomp_utilConfig.cmake](https://github.com/sikang/DecompUtil/blob/master/decomp_utilConfig.cmake) is located at the root of that repo.

Ex. (since you put DecompUtil/ directory under your project's root / source directory)

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/DecompUtil")
find_package(DecompUtil REQUIRED)
```

or

```
set(DecompUtil_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/DecompUtil")
find_package(DecompUtil REQUIRED)
```

decomp_utilConfig.cmake does not define a target named `DecompUtil`, and you already added the include directory using `DECOMP_UTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS`, so I'm pretty sure your `target_link_libraries(test DecompUtil)` is erroneous and should be removed.

Also, there's almost never a reason to mix `add_subdirectory` and `find_package` for a single thing. Your `add_subdirectory(DecompUtil)` should be removed.